# Azure Application Insights - Split custom events by multiple dimensions

Tags: azure-application-insights

I'm new to Azure Application insights.

I have a Custom Event that captures, User and Action.

Is it possible to visualize this so I can see it grouped by Day, with a bar in the chart for each user that is then split by the action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To track the Custom Events, navigate to `Usage=>Events` in Azure Application Insights of your App Service:

- Select `Any CustomEvent` in `Who used` section.
- You can select the other options like `Day, Split` by etc., according to your requirement.

[image]

You can also track the Custom Events using KQL query in `Application Insights=>Logs` :

```
customEvents
| where name == "<customEventName>"
| summarize count() by bin(timestamp, 1d), tostring(customDimensions.user) , tostring(customDimensions.action)
```

You can see the result in Chart section.

[image]

**References:**

1. Refer to [Application Insights - Azure Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/usage-overview?tabs=aspnetcore#custom-business-events) for more details on how to analyze custom events in Azure Application Insights.
2. [Application Insights API for custom events and metrics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-custom-events-metrics)